# The value of attribute "android:name" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character

Tags: android

Extreme novice here tying to figure this error out.

> The value of attribute "android:name" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character

This is generated by something I have created with the addition of the android.hardware.usb.jar I have included as a library I believe.  I can't identify what/which target is "null"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.nitro"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.usb/>

<application
        android:allowBackup="android:false" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"                    
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        <uses-library android:name="android:android.hardware.usb" />
        <android-required ="android:true " />
        <activity android:name="com.nitro.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" 

            <intent-filter
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter
                <action         android:name="android:android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED " />
            </intent-filter>

           <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" 
                      android:resource="@xml/acccessory_filter" />

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am still building and learning. This is just a hobby at this point so go easy on me, this is all out of my comfort zone and I will need detailed explanation.

Thanks
Kyle

Answer (score 4):

```
  <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.usb/>
```

You haven't closed the quote, it should be:

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.usb" />
```

You have also forgotten to close this quote:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER />
```

Should be

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Also, your `application` tag is not closed and `android:false` is not valid:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="android:false" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"                    
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Should be

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="false" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"                    
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

That is not correct:

```
    <uses-library android:name="android:android.hardware.usb" />
    <android-required ="android:true " />
```

As there is no standalone `android-required` tag, that is probably the `android:required` of the `uses-library` tag. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-library-element.html) you can read more on that. It should be like:

```
<uses-library android:name="android:android.hardware.usb" android:required ="true" />
```

Your `intent-filter` tag is not closed:

```
<intent-filter
```

It should be:

```
<intent-filter>
```

---

The whole manifest with all fixed bugs should be like this I believe:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nitro"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library
            android:name="android:android.hardware.usb"
            android:required="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.nitro.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android:android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED " />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/acccessory_filter" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I bumped the end quote over with no change in the error?

The LINT displays at the application string below the <uses-feature line 

Thank you for the catch.

Comment: @user3476157 check my edited answer now, I have edited a lot as you had lots of mistakes.

Comment: @ Nikola Thank you. I think both of you ended up providing nearly the same code.  
I now have this
'code'Description Resource Path Location Type
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'resource' with value '@xml/acccessory_filter'). AndroidManifest.xml /Nitro line 35 Android AAPT Problem
'code' 
I've added what was supposed to be in the file. 

'code' <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?/>
<resourses>
    <usb-accessory manufacturer="Manufacturer" model="Model" version="Version" />
</resourses>

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to add the code to comments with the right syntax. Learning that also I suppose. It took me longer than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and checked the exact text and it was ok but still THE ERROR...

So I fixed copy pasting that line of the manifest (uses-sdk) from another Manifest of a working project and build it nicely!

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
   android:name="android.hardware.usb/>need closing quote

   android:name="android.hardware.usb"/>
```

here try this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.nitro"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.usb"/>

<application
        android:allowBackup="android:false" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"                    
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <uses-library android:name="android:android.hardware.usb" />
        <android-required ="android:true " />
        <activity android:name="com.nitro.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action         android:name="android:android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED " />
            </intent-filter>

           <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" 
                      android:resource="@xml/acccessory_filter" />

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I partially corrected the original issue by changing
    
     android:versionName="1.0" />

Now I have another error

<Description Resource Path Location Type
The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

Comment: this means your missing a closing tag on an element