# Right way to add permissions : titanium android appcelerator

Tags: android, titanium-mobile, android-permissions

I read a lot from stack about permissions ( like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733817) ) but i'm still stuck...

I want to add these three permissions to my app :

```
 android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
 android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
 android.permission.INTERNET
```

So i added this to my tiapp.xml :

```
  <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
    <manifest>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    </manifest>
  </android>
```

And titanium studio says that manifest contains not valid content and one of the value :

```
  {sdk-version, deployment-targets, id, name, version, publisher, url, description, copyright, icon, persistent-wifi, prerendered-icon, statusbar-style, statusbar-hidden, fullscreen, navbar-hidden, analytics, guid, iphone, android, ios, mobileweb, blackberry, tizen, ivi, property, modules, plugins}
```

is expected...

Then I tried :

```
<manifest android:versionName="1.0.0">
```

But the prefix 'android' of the attribute 'android:versionName' associated to an element type 'manifest' isn't bounded

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the error was a basic one :

see this line :

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

well just remove the `"/"` ^^ :

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Comment: used

<manifest>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    </manifest>

as was suggested and made sure to remove the last "/" as recommended as well. Not sure if this helped, but I also checked the "use host gpu" on my AVD I used. Then when I attempted to hit a webpage it worked!

Answer (score 0):

These configuration elements live under the root  tag of the tiapp.xml. Unless otherwise noted, the configuration value goes inside the tag's content, that is,  *VALUE* . [Check this document out](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/tiapp.xml_and_timodule.xml_Reference-section-29004921_tiapp.xmlandtimodule.xmlReference-TopLevelElements) for further reference.

Answer (score -1):

when you say you added it to your tiapp.xml what do you mean?

you should add permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml file like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.etc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```